# "Check Stokes' theorem in the plane where $f(x, y) = y^2\mathbf{i} + x^2\mathbf{j}$ and the region formed is bounded by the circle ($x^2+y^2=4$)."

Tags: calculus, stokes-theorem

[Resolution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/11p5z.png)

"The question is a problem from Leithold's calculus book. I didn't understand the ($x = 5 \cos(t)$). Shouldn't it be ($x = 2 \cos(t)$)?

[Resolution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2wWma.png)

The theorem in the book is this. From what I understand, you calculate both sides of the equality in the theorem and obtain the same value.Rot is curl.
[Theorem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eYZT7.png)
[Theorem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oE8dN.png)

edit: It seems like whoever solved this exercise took a circle from the previous exercise and calculated it for this one, leaving it incorrect. I tried to solve it my way, but I'm struggling to obtain the unit tangent vector and to calculate the line integral. Can someone help me?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Iyog.png)

Comment: Please refrain from using pictures. There are [different reasons](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34123/1273570) for that, for example, the search function doesn’t see them. Use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) instead.

Comment: Was this exercise actually preceded by the quoted text? Because based on the first image, it seems more like the exercise is asking to compute the surface/line integrals of $F$ over $R$/the boundary of $R$, resp.

Comment: Yes, it didn't make sense to me either.

Comment: From what I understand, you calculate both sides of the equality in the theorem and obtain the same value.

Comment: Maybe what looks like a 5 is actually a 2, but it's hard to tell because the photos are incredibly pixelated and impossible to read.

Comment: It seems like whoever solved this exercise took a circle from the previous exercise and calculated it for this one, leaving it incorrect. I tried to solve it my way, but I'm struggling to obtain the unit tangent vector and to calculate the line integral. Can someone help me?

Comment: It's the last image I add.

Comment: The curve is an ellipse, not a circle. Everything is just fine. As far as I can see, the equation $x^2+y^2=4$ is *yours*, not Leithold’s. But, yes, your images are basically illegible. You do not need a unit tangent vector; review the definition of a line integral.